# How to get css style's value from outside in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a .js file which holds global data (actually i am going to fill it from website). Here it is:

```
const DynGlobals = {
    HomePageColor: {
        color: '#e74c3c'
    }
}
/*
or i can set it like this
HomePageColor: '#e74c3c'
/*
export { DynGlobals }
```

I have a view and trying to set it's style from this file. So far i have tried many things to create another const and set it to view's style but didn't work

```
const bgColorStyle = {
    backgroundColor: {DynGlobals.HomePageColor.color}
}
```

with or without bracelets it doesn't work. Any advices on this?

Comment: How are you importing `DynGlobals`? How are you using `bgColorStyle`?

Comment: Yes i did it correctly. Here is how i use it <View style={[styles.menuBarStyle, bgColorStyle]}>

Comment: Are you creating the stylesheet before using it? `StyleSheet.create({...})`

Comment: nope. This is just a const. I never use it that way to be honest. It works when i hardcode it. I am not sure why i need to use StyleSheet

Comment: To be honest using a constant value without the brackets version considering if you are importing it correctly should work. Can you provide some more code from the component you are using it. Maybe it will help to find whats wrong.